# Rookie here,Dont know where to use the try and catch block

Tags: java

I have 3 java programs

1st one:

```
public class Person{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int g1;
    private int g2;
    private int g3;
    private int periodic;



    public Person(String firstname,String lastname,int periodic,int g1,int g2,int g3){
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.periodic=periodic;
        this.g1=g1;
        this.g2=g2;
        this.g3=g3;
    }

    public void print(){

        int a=(g1+g2+g3)/3;
        System.out.println("\t"+ firstname + " "+ lastname);
        System.out.println("Periodic Exam: " + periodic);
        System.out.println("Grade of quiz 1: "+g1);
        System.out.println("Grade of quiz 2: "+g2);
        System.out.println("Grade of quiz 3: "+g3);
        System.out.println("Average of the quizzes: "+a);
    }


}
```

Second one:

```
public class Student extends Person{  //inherits Person//

    public Student(String firstname,String lastname,int periodic,int g1,int g2,int g3){
        super(firstname,lastname,periodic,g1,g2,g3);    
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Student Details:");
        super.print();

    }
}
```

Third one:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Person persons[] = new Person[3];
        persons[0] = new Student("Robert","Almazan",91,90,85,86);
        persons[1] = new Student("Dennis","Navan",92,89,84,87);
        persons[2] = new Student("Allan","Villariza",93,79,81,84);

        for(Person person:persons){
            person.print();

        }
}
```

All i want to do is catch exceptions when i alter persons[] like this

```
Person persons[] = new Person[3];
        persons[0] = new Student("Robert","Almazan","ZZ",0,-85,86);
        persons[1] = new Student("Dennis","Navan","ASA",0,-84,87);
        persons[2] = new Student("Allan","Villariza","sa",0,-81,84);
```

I tried doing it like this

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){


    try{

        Person persons[] = new Person[3];
        persons[0] = new Student("Robert","Almazan","ZZ",90,85,86);
        persons[1] = new Student("Dennis","Navan","ASA",89,84,87);
        persons[2] = new Student("Allan","Villariza","9",79,81,84);

        for(Person person:persons){
            person.print();



        }
    }//try
    catch(ArithmeticException e){

        System.out.println("Arithmetic Error");
    }

    catch(InputMismatchException e){

        System.out.println("Input Error");
    }
    finally{

        System.out.println("Thank you");
    }


    }//main
}
```

the program doesnt catch exceptions

When i compile,it still says Errors like String cannot be converted to int,it always accept negative numbers and it doesnt catch exceptions

need help...

Comment: My Java is rusty, but shouldn't ` Person persons[] = new Person[3];` be ` Person[] persons = new Person[3];`?

Comment: @soong to my knowledge, both is ok. Zer0: Probably you should try to separate what are separate problems: Who is 'it'? The Compiler? What exception do you get? Why do you expect that negative numbers will not be accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
persons[0] = new Student("Robert","Almazan","ZZ",0,-85,86); 
                                            ^^^^
```

is a compile time error because third parameter that you accept is of int type

```
public Student(String firstname,String lastname,int periodic,int g1,int g2,int g3){
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can only catch exception at **run time** and **not at compile time.**

Comment: I think it should be Student Class's Constructor instead of Person Class .

Answer (score 1):

> When i compile,it still says Errors like String cannot be converted to
>   int,it always accept negative numbers and it doesnt catch exceptions

Firstly **Exception** occurs at **run-time** not at **compile time** , Since your program has a compile time error which is quite self explanatory i.e. `String cannot be converted into int` .

The Problem is

```
new Student("Robert","Almazan","ZZ",0,-85,86);
                                /\
                                ||
                              This is String not an int
```

But your Student Class Constructor is Like this

```
public Student(String firstname,String lastname,int periodic,int g1,int g2,int g3)
                                                      /\
                                                      ||
                                                    int not String
```

This is why compile time error is coming, Now your program has not even compiled successfully , So No Chances of [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) untill your program runs.